# Is it possible to check for a specific date before installation?

Tags: windows-installer

My VS2005 setup project installer needs to check a specific date before it can be installed. I tried this programatically by overriding the OnBeforeInstall but the installation proceeds first before it gets checked. I also tried the Launch Condition on the setup project (e.g., %Date > somedate) but I cannot find a good example on this. Can someone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: @trojanfoe: I guess he was talking about planet alignment. :)

Comment: Sorry guys, just a typo error >_<

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Visual Studio. You need a setup authoring tool which allows you to add your custom action before [LaunchConditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369751%28VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) action in [InstallUISequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369543%28VS.85%29.aspx) table.

Even then, you would need a win32 DLL or VBScript custom action to tell the installer to stop. For example, you could set an installer property which is used as a launch condition. This cannot be done with an installer class action.

Try re-examining why you need to check the date and ask a more specific question. Perhaps there are other solutions.